# 3-bone IK chain not rotating properly, why?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I ran into a weird bug where my 3-bone IK chain isn't behaving as expected. I've made other quadrupeds in the past and had no problem like this. As far as I can tell, the IK constraint is also exactly the same as all others I've made. Here are some GIF examples.

This is what I would expect from a good 3-bone IK leg: https://gyazo.com/98754f4cdb2f08d87d9ce5734c5b367e

This is what I'm getting now, the upper bones are barely rotating:
https://gyazo.com/0ea27bb19a79a998cf1cfe44400b36c5

Comment: Did you check the stiffness values of every bone of the chain in the Inverse Kinematics tab of the armature properties panel?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the severity of the rotation in the chain directly effects how well the IK will work. A subtle rotation isn't enough, but as soon as I bend the chain a bit more in edit mode, the IK picks up quite a bit of rotation.